# Dynamic core-animated-pages in Polymer

Tags: node.js, polymer

I'm new to polymer and I'm developing an app with it and Node.js. The app listens to a port and when it receives something, it is displayed in the page. I'm using core-animated-pages and I want to change the page content with a **transition** when it receives something from the listening port (exactly like topeka quiz https://polymer-topeka.appspot.com/ ).

What is the best approach to accomplishing this?

Comment: Fixed spelling typos and made it more readable.

Comment: Great question, what did you end up doing?